# Change color of polygon (country) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, color

I have a txt file added like a layer to QGIS 3.4.2. File number 1. It is an attribute table.

I have a shapefile (a map) added to QGIS 3.4.2. This shapefile has all the countries of the world.

Both files are joined by a key field.

In the file number 1 I have a list of countries:

Key file - Name country - Color

1 - Canada - #000000
2 - US - #FFCC00

How can I change the background of all the countries of the map with the field "color" of every country?

Answer (score 3):

Open `symbology tab` of your layer and select `data defined override` at `fill color`, as `field type` choose `your color field`.

[image]